# Do you have to specify to require Zend_mail or not, if you have added to the include_path?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got a few Framework folders and plugins in the `xampp/library` folder.

I've included it in my `php.ini include_path`.

But when I use:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
```

It can't find it.

So i added:

```
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
```

and it worked...

Should I specify each folder seperately in `php.ini` or is including the entire Library folder fine...

Answer (score 2):

You need to require `Zend.php` so that autoloading starts working. Setting the include path means when you provide file names in your require or include statements php will search on those folders to see if a matching file exist. Include path does not mean auto load.